# Context Menu being created if you install 7-Zip or TortoiseSVN in Windows 7 while it works just fine in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, 7-zip

I've installed 7-Zip in XP and it creates a context-menu in Windows Explorer. But, in Windows 7 it doesn't. I don't know why. I tried it with administrator privileges, but nothing happened.

Comment: Version 7-Zip 9.20 (2010-11-18) for Windows .msi 64-bit x64 works well with context menu under Windows-7

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on my installation.

Open 7-Zip and go to `Tools > Options` select the `Plugins` tab and select `7-Zip` then click `Options`.

Make sure that they are ticked. If it isn't perhaps file this as a bug report, but it certainly works here.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it isn't working.

Comment: Must be a bug then - I would personally try unticking the boxes then apply / ok, and retick just to see, but Sorry - I cannot reproduce this. FYI, I am using version 4.65

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I'm on 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Windows 7 uses different context menus for 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

I fixed this problem by installing the **64-bit v9.10 beta** version of 7-Zip. I then opened it as an administrator. I was then able to set 7-Zip file associations and apply the context menu.